# Tensor flow not using my nvidia quadro k1000m , says that some libraries are missing

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

Using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[image: Tensorflow Errors]

I don't know how I am missing these libraries. I have installed all of the Tensor Flow and CUDA libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You more than likely just need to add these to your `~/.bashrc` or similar

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64/:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

Just note before you put them in your `~/.bashrc` just check these paths do exist
We might have different versions

```
ls /usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64/
```